# Problema al escribir en un archivo .TXT con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo este código;

```
 while(num <= cont1)
        {
            n1 = dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            n2 = dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = int.Parse(n1) * int.Parse(n2);
            dataGridView3.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = "100%";
            dataGridView3.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = int.Parse(n1) * int.Parse(dataGridView3.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            if (num == cont1-1)
            {
                StreamReader leerTEMP = new StreamReader("c:\\ACEROX\\TEMP2.txt");
                string cadena = leerTEMP.ReadLine();
                leerTEMP.Close();

                int x = 0, y = 0;
                //LOS SIGUIENTES DOS BUCLES WHILE SON LOS DEL PROBLEMA.
                StreamWriter WriTemp1 = new StreamWriter("c:\\ACEROX\\TEMP.txt", true);
                StreamWriter WriTemp2 = new StreamWriter("c:\\ACEROX\\TEMP2.txt", true);
                while (x <= int.Parse(cadena))
                        {                        
                        WriTemp1.WriteLine(dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        //if(x == int.Parse(cadena))                           
                        x += 1;
                        }                 
                while (y <= int.Parse(cadena))
                        {
                        WriTemp2.WriteLine(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        //if (x == int.Parse(cadena))
                        y += 1;
                        }
                WriTemp1.Close();
                WriTemp2.Close();
            }  
            num += 1;
        }           
    }
```

como pueden ver, tengo 2 bucles while, los cuales escriben celda por celda el contenido del DGV dentro de un archivo .txt, VIsual Studio no me lanza ningún error de cualquier tipo, pero no entiendo porque el STREAMWRITER no modifica nada dentro del archivo de exto (.txt).

Este código está dentro del LOAD proncipal del FORM, pero no lo pongo todo para no hacerlo muy extenso.

Comment: ¿Que me dices de esta parte en tus ciclos `int.Parse(cadena)` estas seguro que obtienes un valor entero mayor a cero?

Comment: Te lanza algún error en tiempo de ejecución, intenta poniendo un `try catch`

Comment: Como bien te ha dicho @denifersantiagofernandez, lo primero que debes comprobar es que contiene `cadena`

Comment: Deberías depurar tu código como primera opción. Este tipo de errores son muy simples de resolver depurando.

Comment: Este codigo tiene tantos errores que no se por donde empezar. Escribis una y otra vez los mismos archivos. Con los mismos datos. Toda la logica de lo que intentas hacer es confusa. Los dos while no tienen sentido de ser, porque son lo mismo. Estaria bueno que explicaras que queres hacer

Comment: logré resolverlo haciendo la comprobación de la cadena antes, gracias por los consejos, y si estoy de acuerdo en que debo de optimizar mi forma de programar... gracias

Answer (score 1):

no probé tu código, pero yo hace tiempo hice algo similar pero diferente, puedes tomarlo todo o lo que te sirva.

```
    public static class Save
    {
        private readonly static DateTime FileName = DateTime.Now;
        private readonly static string PathFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Log" + FileName.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "") + ".txt");

        internal static void Log(string Text) {

            if (CreateFile(PathFile))
            {

                string line = "";


    using (var fileStream = File.Open(PathFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {

                    line = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            line += Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + " " + Text;
            File.WriteAllText(PathFile, line, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
    }

    internal static void OutDateLog() {
        string Select = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string From = "*.txt";

        string[] pathFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Select, From);
        foreach (var item in pathFiles)
        {
            var Create = File.GetCreationTime(item);
            if (Create < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
            {
                File.Delete(item);
            }
        }

    }

    private static bool CreateFile(string where)
    {
        bool created = true;
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(where))
            {
                File.Create(where).Close();
            }
        }
        catch {
            created = false;
        }
        return created;
    }
}
```

mira el createFile crea el archivo txt en la ruta de la solucion esto funciona junto con Log(string Text) a este metodo le pasas el texto que deseas agregar y listo hace todo por ti, ten en cuenta que este metodo genera un archivo por dia.
y este otro metodo OutDateLog() borra los archivos mayores a 30 dias, espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Esta respuesta carece de calidad, por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y asi te evitas recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Gracias!! usare tu código para optimizar el mio, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Ntp estamos para ayudar.